# HBase KeyValue.getKey() returns extra characters

Tags: hbase

the following hBase code returns some weird characters on the front of my rowKey:

> "\u0000""\u0014""ei:shrimp:-749…."

The prepended weird characters are '\u0000' and '\u0014', and sometimes '\u0016'. I put quotes in the above line to make it readable. There are only two and they're prepended to my rowkey. The key should be 'ei:shrimp:-749...'. Here is the code that I use to get the keys back:

```
import static org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes.toBytes;

List<KeyValue> kvs = result.list();
        String key = null;
        for (KeyValue kv : kvs) {
            String value = Bytes.toString(kv.getValue());
            String qualifier = Bytes.toString(kv.getQualifier());
            if(key == null) {
                key = Bytes.toString(kv.getKey());
```

Here is the code I used to create my put:

```
public Put createPut(String columnFamily) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(this.getGroup()).append(':');
        sb.append(this.getKey()).append(':').append(this.getCoordinateHash());

        Put p = new Put(toBytes(sb.toString()));
        p = p.add(toBytes(columnFamily), toBytes(COLUMN_VALUE), toBytes(this.getValue()));
```

Any idea what those weird characters are? What am I doing wrong?
Thank you,
Rajat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to call KeyValue.getRow().

KeyValue.getKey() returns the raw key, and the first two bytes are a Short that indicates how long the row is.